# Firestore Recyclerview: No content is being loaded

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried the following code to try firestore recyclreview. But it looks like no content is being loaded. And yes, adapter.startListening() is being called onStart.

```
    query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("users")
            .document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .collection("posts");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(query, Post.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, NewsfeedViewholder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(NewsfeedViewholder holder, int position, Post model) {
            holder.setView(model.getContent());
        }

        @Override
        public NewsfeedViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
            return new NewsfeedViewholder(view);
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```